# How to access generated instances systemverilog and Vivado 2014.1?

Tags: system-verilog, vivado

[image: The module]
I generate instanced using the following code:
[image: Generation]

I try to access them like that:
R[0].router3d.address= 0 ; // for example

The simulation went fine But the code is not synthesizable with the following error:
Cannot resolve hierarchical name.

Any idea why ?

Answer (score 2):

Easy way to find the full path is to add `initial $display("%m");` to your `Router_2D` and `Router_3D`. Then simulate without trying to access the path. `%m` displays the hierarchical name, see [IEEE Std 1800-2012](https://standards.ieee.org/findstds/standard/1800-2012.html) § 21.2.1.2 *Format specifications*.

Since you are nt specifying a label in the if-statement, the hierarchical name will likely be `R[0].genblk1.router3d.address`. This is explained in [IEEE Std 1800-2012](https://standards.ieee.org/findstds/standard/1800-2012.html) § 27.6 *External names for unnamed generate blocks*:

> Although an unnamed generate block has no name that can be used in a hierarchical name, it needs to have a name by which external interfaces can refer to it. A name will be assigned for this purpose to each unnamed generate block as described in the next paragraph.
>   Each generate construct in a given scope is assigned a number. The number will be 1 for the construct that appears textually first in that scope and will increase by 1 for each subsequent generate construct in that scope. All unnamed generate blocks will be given the name “`genblk<n>`” where `<n>` is the number assigned to its enclosing generate construct. If such a name would conflict with an explicitly declared name, then leading zeros are added in front of the number until the name does not conflict.
>   <sub>NOTE—Each generate construct is assigned its number as described in the previous paragraph even if it does not contain any unnamed generate blocks.</sub>

Comment: I used $display("%m"); and I got testBn.R[0].router3d, testBn.R[1].router3d, testBn.R[2].router2d and so on ...... .When i try to use these names again i got hierarchical error and i see no genblk in the name displayed using "%m"?

Comment: Sounds like your simulator is not IEEE complicate. Try specifying your own hierarchical label name as described in section 27 of the standard.

Comment: I am using Vivado2014.1, Is this not IEEE standard  ?

Comment: Not sure what version of IEEE 1800 Vivado 2014.1 is supporting. 1800-2005 doesn't have the `genblkN` language but it could be they didn't implement the feature yet. Did you try adding your own label name?

Comment: I tried something like: for (....) begin:R if (...) begin F: Router_3D #(.ramSize(4)) router3d (.port(dummy,links[0],links[1],links[2],links[3]),.clk(clk)) , then i try to access it like that:R[0].F.router3d.address = 0 ;  AND still the same error

Comment: This is a Vivado specific issue. You probably should try Xilinx fourms or contact Xilinx directly

Comment: http://forums.xilinx.com/t5/Synthesis/Synth-8-146-cannot-resolve-hierarchical-name/td-p/370713